# Cannot view my new MVC 4 application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

I just created a new basic MVC 4 application in VS 2010. I just clicked the play button to test it came up in the web browser and I'm getting the following page:

[image]

I think I need to change my virtual path to something but I don't know what.

EDIT: Can't see what it says properly in the picture:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


The resource cannot be found. 
  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

 Requested URL: /
```

Comment: What files do you have in your project? Which template did you use exactly?

Comment: I created an Empty project. It has all the default files.

Comment: Does it map any routes in `Global.asax.cs` or `App_Start` or anywhere similar? I can't remember what the MVC 4 templates generate by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No one person gave me the full answer. So this is an amalgamation of @MattiVirkkunen and @BrettAlfred

Add this within RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Home" }
            );
```

Add this within HomeController.cs

```
public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

If you created an Empty Project you will need to create a HomeController with an Index Action.  You will also need to create a View in ~/Views/Home/ called Index.

The other project templates create this for you but the Empty Project does not.

```
public class HomeController : Controller 
{

     public ActionResult Index()
     {

          return View()
     }

}
```

Comment: Can I set a .aspx file as my start page in this way? By using `public ActionResult Login()
     {

          return View()
     }`

Comment: You want the default page to be the login page?  You really shouldn't be using .aspx but using .cshtml

Comment: @Neeta: There's no reason whatsoever to use an `.aspx` file with MVC 4.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen What are you supposed to use?

Comment: @Neeta: For views? Razor (`.cshtml`).

Comment: @BrettAllred Just for now, it'll change once I've created the correct default page

Comment: @Neeta : If you create a Login action you can access it by going to /Home/Login.  If you want that to be the default then you need to change your default route in Global.asax.cs

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I think I'm going to use aspx. Is that going to be problematic for me?

Comment: @Neeta: Why would you create an MVC 4 application and then use .aspx?

Answer (score 0):

Kya Neeta MVC me neyi ho Kya?? I am too :)

I think u have created a start-up page in your applicaition. 
Type Http: //localhost:8080/Home/Index  in your url

http: //localhost:/ControllerName/ActionName

if that does not work please create a new MVC application from scratch.